# Using Negative Range for Bessel Function Results in 2 Values

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

I am using the inbuilt function of matlab to calculate the bessel function of second order, following is the code

```
format long
z = (-5:1:5)';

 y = bessely(1,z)
plot (y)
```

The output is as follows

> y =
>
> -0.147863143391227 + 0.655158275182930i
>
> -0.397925710557100 + 0.132086656047098i
>
> -0.324674424791800 - 0.678117917051873i
>
> 0.107032431540937 - 1.153449615513747i
>
> 0.781212821300289 - 0.880101171489867i
>
> ```
>            -Inf
> ```
>
> -0.781212821300289
>   -0.107032431540937
>     0.324674424791800
>     0.397925710557100
>     0.147863143391227

What i don't understand is why am i getting two values when the value of z is negative ?

Comment: In addition to the given answers, compare your output with the result of simply taking the square root: `z.^0.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
-0.147863143391227 + 0.655158275182930i
```

is not two values, it's a single *complex number*. See the `i` at the right of the second part ?  That's Matlab's way of telling you that that second number is the imaginary part of the number, the one which is multiplied by `i`, the square root of -1.

Matlab is telling you, and I concur with Matlab on this, that that function returns complex values for negative inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Two values?! It's a complex number! That is, a number of the form x+yi, where `i` is the square root of -1.